# Sequelize combine 2 queries as sub where

Tags: sequelize.js, subquery

I have 2 tables `SocialPostEntity` and `ResearchEntity`.
`ResearchEntity` has a field `relatedId` which represent the `SocialPostEntity.id`.
In my mapping, `ResearchEntity.relatedId` is not mapped, it is just an integer for abstraction reasons. no foreign key either.
I want to have the following in a single query:

```
select * from ResearchEntity where relatedId in (select id  from SocialPostEntity);
```

For now, I have solved it in 2 different queries, which is not efficient at all:

```
const fromPosts = await SocialPostEntity.findAll({ attributes: ['id'], where: { status: 1 } });
const allRelated = await ResearchEntity.findAll({ where: { postId: fromPosts.map(x => x.id) } });
```

I don't want to use native SQL string query, I want to use sequlize query API.
Is that possible to combine "in" statement and select? `in (select id  from SocialPostEntity)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature request is still open: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9509.

The [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html) refers to the `sequelize.literal` utility to perform subqueries, which is the approach used by [similar questions](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3961):

```js
const subquery = sequelize.dialect.queryGenerator.selectQuery(SocialPostEntity.tableName, {
    attributes: ['id'],
    where: { status: 1 }
}).slice(0, -1);

const allRelated = await ResearchEntity.findAll({
    where: { postId: { [Op.in] : sequelize.literal(`( ${subquery} )`) } }
});
```

Comment: nice! I think whis is what im after. ill test it out and reward you. thanks!!!